# Using MVC Razor variable with ng-required

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

I want to set ng-required to the razor model variable value but it does not work.

It works fine for setting classes but I am not using the angularjs attribute. It works with class but not ng-class:

```
ng-required="@(Model.IsNotesRequired)"
```

Is it possible to use razor variables with angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can combine angularjs with razor. Try this:

```
ng-required="@Model.IsNotesRequired.ToString().ToLower()"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Bill P. That did it.